# Php and Mysqli with transaction

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a problem with transaction, because if I try to enter a wrong query,
the system should not enter either.

Instead the system inserts the first query, and the second is not,
and does not enter the Rollback

This is my code:

```
$conn = connect();

try {
     /* set autocommit to off */
     $conn->autocommit(FALSE);

    /* MY QUERY */
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO `transazioni` (`id`, `nome`, `numero`) VALUES (NULL, 'luca', '12')");
    $conn->query("I--NSERT INTO `transazioni` (`id`, `nome`, `numero`) VALUES (NULL, 'paolo', '12')");

   /* commit transaction */
   $conn->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
      // faccio rollback
      $conn->rollback();
      echo "enter in rollback";
}
```

How can i fix it ?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by mysql engine. MyISAM doesn't support transactions, you have to change to InnoDB.

Also note that your catch block woudn't work unless you [configure mysqli for that explicitly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli)

Comment: can i tranform my db to InnoDB and don't lost any data ?

Comment: I checked now, I'm using innodb!